# Localize WP8 App

Tags: windows-phone-8, localization

My windows phone 8 app have to be published in English and Arabic versions. I have created the resource strings in default language that is en-US and then have created the translations by "MultilingualAppToolkit" that generated the ar-SA files.

I changed the phone language and restarted the phone and experienced a strange scenario :

> App bar orientation and messages are in arabic but screen flow and strings are in english.

Another question is i have to give user the option to change the language regardless of the phone language. so how can i change the language settings on application initialization.

Comment: Show your code, how do you use stings.

Comment: it is standard as given below

Comment: public class LocalizedStrings
    {
        private static AppResources _localizedResources = new AppResources(); and Text="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.lblComment, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}"

        public AppResources LocalizedResources { get { return _localizedResources; } }
    }

Comment: in fact my AppResources object is not initializing with proper locale

Comment: Do you have LocalizedResources added in Appx.xaml?

Comment: everything was perfect, i had to initialize the cultur in phoneappstarting method, its working now thanks